# Unix Domain Socket configuration in Spring Boot Webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

Spring Boot version: 2.4.0
Reactor netty now supports [Unix Domain Sockets](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/snapshot/reference/index.html#_unix_domain_sockets_3) while initializing server.

I am trying to custmoize Spring Boot `HttpServer` to use unix domain socket instead of http port using

```java
@Configuration
public class NettyConfig {

    @Bean
    public NettyReactiveWebServerFactory factory() {
        NettyReactiveWebServerFactory factory = new NettyReactiveWebServerFactory();
        factory.setServerCustomizers(Collections.singletonList(new NettyServerCustomizer() {
            @Override
            public HttpServer apply(HttpServer httpServer) {
                return httpServer.bindAddress(() -> new DomainSocketAddress("/tmp/test.sock"));
            }
        }));
        return factory;
    }
}
```

But application is unable to start with given stacktrace:

```java
13:05:36.706 ERROR [restartedMain] SpringApplication.reportFailure:856 :    Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:942)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:591)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:63)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298)
    at com.avis.biverve.EntryPoint.main(EntryPoint.java:25)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at reactor.netty.DisposableServer.port(DisposableServer.java:69)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer.getPort(NettyWebServer.java:193)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer.start(NettyWebServer.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.WebServerManager.start(WebServerManager.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:40)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178)
    ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed in Spring Boot version 2.4.2

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/24529